# vue-storefront 2.623.0 page stop rendering the page

Tags: vue-storefront

I have a page in a vue-storefront 2.623.0, this page stops the vue app from rendering, this means the footer will not be displayed.

This problem appears randomly, i.e after a specific number of refreshes it stops from rendering, or may be from the first visit.

i tried chrome developer tools and thought that it will give me some indicators but that does not happened.